# ORACLE FUNCTION || SQL Statement Ignored

Tags: oracle, function

I am trying to write a function that will calculate the percentage of cars that have been rented at least 5 times in relation to all cars.

My question is - How to count cars that have been rented more than 5 times?
I attach a schema of my tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ZADANIE3

RETURN NUMBER IS

ALL_CARS NUMBER;
MORE_THAN_5 NUMBER;
WYNIK NUMBER;

cursor c1 IS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WYPOZYCZENIE;

cursor c2 IS
//SELECT ALL CARS WHICH HAS BEEN LOANED MORE THAN 5 TIMES?

BEGIN
OPEN c1;
FETCH C1 INTO ALL_CARS;
CLOSE c1;

OPEN c2;
FETCH c2 INTO MORE_THAN_5;
CLOSE c2;

RETURN ALL_CARS/MORE_THAN_5*100;
END;
```

My tables:

```
create table samochod(
id_samochod number(6) primary key,
id_producent number(6) references producent(id_producent),
model varchar2(30),
stan varchar2(20)
);

create table wypozyczenie(
id_wypozyczenie number(10) primary key,
id_klient number(10) references klient(id_klient),
id_pracownik number(6) references pracownik(id_pracownika),
id_samochod number(6) references samochod(id_samochod),
stan varchar2(30),
data_wypozyczenia date default(sysdate),
data_zwrotu date default(null));
```

Comment: I believe you should translate your tables. This way it's really hard for people to help you

Comment: @Tacoo - translation is not required. What *is* required is a question. All I see here is a bunch of code and some table definitions. I do not see anything being asked. Please **edit your question** and explain what the question is. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica My question is - How to count cars that have been rented more than 5 times(see comment in code)?

Comment: @Tacoo : What did you tried ?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica SELECT count(counter) INTO more_than_5 FROM (SELECT count(*) counter FROM wypozyczenie GROUP BY id_samochod HAVING count(*)>=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ZADANIE3
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  ALL_CARS     NUMBER;
  MORE_THAN_5  NUMBER;
  WYNIK        NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO ALL_CARS
    FROM SAMOCHOD;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO MORE_THAN_5
    FROM (SELECT ID_SAMOCHOD, COUNT(*) AS HIRE_COUNT
            FROM WYPOZYCZENIE
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 5);

  RETURN ALL_CARS/MORE_THAN_5*100;
END;
```